# Combine two rows specific column if data is same?

Tags: excel, merge

I have input like below

[image]

I need output like below

Basically how to merge only column A adjacent values if data is same with formula? It's an huge sheet. I want to apply formula so that task is automated .

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: @ScottCraner updated my post .

Comment: Formulas will not do this, You will need vba code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub G()

    Dim x&, start&, bottom&
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    '// Start from row two
    '// In your sample it's value "Text1"
    x = 2

    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1))

        '// "start" designates the start row with new text (see below)
        start = x

        '// As soon as we defined start row with new text, it's time to define the last row.
        '// Cells(x, 1) - is new text value
        '// SearchDirection:=xlPrevious means that search must be done from bottom of sought range
        '// This also means that no extra data must be under your data.
        '// So, this way we can get to know full range.
        '// For single distinct value the start and bottom will be the same row.
        bottom = Range("A:A").Find(Cells(x, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        '// Having start and bottom rows,
        '// we can get full range with new text by using Resize property.
        '// It sets new number of rows and columns having top-left cell as a start point.
        Cells(start, 1).Resize(bottom - start + 1).Merge

        '// The next cell after bottom cell is new value.
        x = bottom + 1

    Wend

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to put the caveat that the data must be sorted on column A, otherwise one runs the risk of merging the wrong number of cells, that this code will merge everything between the first instance and the last instance whether there is any other text between.

Comment: @johnyL Thanks. Can you please explain it ion brief . I come from java back ground. I do not see anywhere in above code where we compare column 1 data  ?

Comment: @ScottCraner Judging by OP's sample, the data *is* in column `A`. :) I will point out to the "text in-between".

Comment: @JohnyL never disputed the location of the data, just that the OP must sort on column A before running the code to ensure correct merging.  Otherwise good use of `Find`.  I would not have thought of that, I would have used `Application.Countif`. Yours will be quicker.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I agree with you that `Find` must be used with caution. One needs to be sure that no gaps or extra data will sneak in. :)